# Do not understand how the JSON object keys is handled in a node.js app

Tags: html, node.js, json, spotify

This is a newbie question.

I have tested the web-api-auth-examples:
https://github.com/spotify/web-api-auth-examples

It works as expected but what I do not understand is how the html code gets the correct data

```
<dt>Display name</dt><dd class="clearfix">{{display_name}}</dd>
```

In this case the data is from a response in app.js:

```
var options = {
  url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me',
  headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token },
  json: true
};
request.get(options, function(error, response, body) {
   console.log(body);
});
```

The response is a JSON Object (https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/object-model/#user-object-private)
which has a key for display_name which is string containing:

> The name displayed on the user’s profile. null if not available.

What I do not understand is how the html file gets the JSON object content by just using the key name in the html code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are using handlebars, which does the data binding.  See line 62 in `index.html`

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/2.0.0-alpha.1/handlebars.min.js"></script>
```

In otherwords, seeing a reference to `{{display_name}}` gets replaced with the actual value of the given object key.  This is done via the handlebars template, defined between lines 34 and 52, within the `script` tag:

```
<script id="user-profile-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <h1>Logged in as {{display_name}}</h1>
  <div class="media">
    <div class="pull-left">
      <img class="media-object" width="150" src="{{images.0.url}}" />
    </div>
    <div class="media-body">
      <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>Display name</dt><dd class="clearfix">{{display_name}}</dd>
        <dt>Id</dt><dd>{{id}}</dd>
        <dt>Email</dt><dd>{{email}}</dd>
        <dt>Spotify URI</dt><dd><a href="{{external_urls.spotify}}">{{external_urls.spotify}}</a></dd>
        <dt>Link</dt><dd><a href="{{href}}">{{href}}</a></dd>
        <dt>Profile Image</dt><dd class="clearfix"><a href="{{images.0.url}}">{{images.0.url}}</a></dd>
        <dt>Country</dt><dd>{{country}}</dd>
      </dl>
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
```

Read up on Handlebars and I'm sure you can figure it out. :)

Comment: Thanks, that was the help needed